# Use Regex to insert a carriage return before a particular pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have scraped a website here is the result:

```
Description
Cap: 4-9 cm Pale brown - often lighter towards the edge. 
Viscid when wet.Gills: Pale clay-brown. Free. Gill edge exude droplets 
when moist which dry to form dark spots.Stem: Off-white. Mealy towards 
the apex.Spores: Clay-brownFlesh: Firm, white. Smell of 
radishesHabitat: In groups or rings on the ground in mixed 
woodlandFrequency: Very Common
```

I need to add a carriage before the words which precede the colon eg. \r\nGills: in order to make the information more readable.

Is re.sub() the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
text_with_rc=re.sub(r'\.\s*',r'.\r\n',the_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes re.sub is required for this. Try the below pattern

```
str1=re.sub(r'(\w*:)',r'\r\n\1',string)
>>> print str1
Description


Cap: 4-9 cm Pale brown - often lighter towards the edge. 
Viscid when wet.

Gills: Pale clay-brown. Free. Gill edge exude droplets 
when moist which dry to form dark spots.

Stem: Off-white. Mealy towards 
the apex.

Spores: Clay-

brownFlesh: Firm, white. Smell of 


radishesHabitat: In groups or rings on the ground in mixed 


woodlandFrequency: Very Common
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep this was spot on.

Comment: @0_o glad to know that it helped. if that answers your question update the post as answered